# Run (remote) php script from (local) python script

Tags: php, python

How do I make python (local) run php script **on a remote server**?

I don't want to process its output with python script or anything, just execute it and meanwhile quit python (while php script will be already working and doing its job).

edit:
What I'm trying to achieve:

- python script connects to ftp server and uploads php script (I already have this part of code)
- it runs php script (that's part of code i'm asking about)
- python script continues to do something else
- python script quits (but probably php script still didn't finished its work so i don't want it to end when it'll exit python)
- python script quit, php script still continues its task

(I *don't* plan to do anything with php output in python - python just has to upload php script and make it start working)

Hope I'm more clear now. Sorry if my question wasn't specific enough.

another edit:
Also please note that I don't have shell access on remote server. I have only ftp and control panel (cpanel); trying to use ftp for it.

Comment: i don't want to include it and use its output, i want to do equivalent of what happens when user enters php script's address in browser

Comment: @Phil, please update your question to explain this more fully.  The comment makes almost no sense.  Python isn't a browser and won't render the HTML the way a browser would.  Please provide some more detailed explanation of what you want to happen.

Comment: ok, i edited it. i don't want to render anything. i'm not sure if i'm approaching problem correctly, but i wrote list of what i want to happen - if i can achieve it differently feel free to comment.

Comment: @Phil: "it runs php script (that's part of code i'm asking about)"  Do you want Python on your local box run some script a remote server?  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes, exactly (hmmmmmmmmmm 15 characters)

Comment: @Phil: If you want to know how to run a remote process (PHP or anything else for that matter) please update your question to emphasize that you want to run a *remote* process on another host.  Makes this crystal clear, if you can.  Otherwise, you won't get any useful help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923691/how-to-start-a-process-on-a-remote-server-disconnect-then-later-collect-output

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946946/how-to-execute-a-process-remotely-using-python

Comment: "let's say located in the same dir" or it's on a remote server?  Which is it?  Please update the question to be correct and consistent.

Comment: I updated it. Note that I don't have shell access. I have ftp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If python is on a different physical machine than the PHP script, I'd make sure the PHP script is web-accessible and use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to call to that url

```
import urllib2

urllib2.urlopen("http://remotehost.com/myscript.php")
```

Comment: Finally something useful! Will have to check if it works, but if it works it's exactly what I want to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
os.system("php yourscript.php")
```

Another alternative would be:

```
# will return new process' id
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, "php yourscript.php")
```

You can check all os module documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).

Comment: ok, will this kill my php script if i'll quit python while php script is still running?

Comment: Why do I need to type 15 characters when the correct answer is "yes"? :-)

So: Yes, it will.

Comment: ok... see my question edit - i'm searching for something that will let php script continue its task even if python will already finish

Comment: is it possible to send value from python file to php file

Answer (score 1):

I'll paraphrase the answer to [How do I include a PHP script in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060436/how-do-i-include-a-php-script-in-python).

```
import subprocess

def php(script_path):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['php', script_path] )
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for noob question, but since it's on remote server how do I specify path? Can it be url? Also, will php script continue working even if python will quit?