# PHP exec to run a file

Tags: php, exec

I am trying for last 3 hours to tell PHP to run a simple file. I am using wamp server for windows in local host (Windows 8)

I've tried with `exec()` working with:

```
 echo exec('whoami');
```

I got response nt authority.

Also tested with:

```
if(function_exists('exec')) {
echo "exec is enabled";
}
```

So it probably works?

I am trying to run a file called tester.php

When I include it, its working, when I require it its working. I need to execute it in background. When I refresh file, code is working without any error, it writes to the database normally.

When i try to exec it its not working.

I tried :

```
       exec("php http://localhost/diplomski/program/defender/tester.php");
       exec("php-cli http://localhost/diplomski/program/defender/tester.php");
       exec("http://localhost/diplomski/program/defender/tester.php");
```

Not working, also tried:

```
        exec("php http://127.0.0.1/diplomski/program/defender/tester.php");
        exec("php-cli http://127.0.0.1/diplomski/program/defender/tester.php");
        exec("php-cli d:\wamp\www\diplomski\program\defender/tester.php")
```

Not working also tried:

```
        exec("php tester.php");
        exec("php-cli tester.php");
        exec("tester.php");
```

Also tried:

```
         $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
         $oExec = $WshShell->Run("D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php-win.exe -f d:\wamp \www\diplomski\program\defender/tester.php", 0, false);
```

Tried this, its refreshing infinitely and not working:

```
        exec("php d:\wamp\www\diplomski\program\defender/tester.php");
        exec("php-cli d:\wamp\www\diplomski\program\defender/tester.php");
        exec("d:\wamp\www\diplomski\program\defender/tester.php");
```

I'm starting to pull my hair out here. First time I'm trying to use `exec()` and I'm not very good with it or with the commands.

Comment: is php added to the env variables?

Comment: The ones with URLs definitely won't work.  What would you expect the PHP interpreter to do with just a URL?  It needs PHP code to run.  For the last attempts, what was the error specifically?  Is PHP part of the path environment variable for that user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Give the full path to the PHP executable and the full path to the PHP script.  You can save the output in `$output` to see what the script produced:

```
exec("d:/path/to/php.exe d:/wamp/www/diplomski/program/defender/tester.php", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) What version of php? If it is older then 5.4.0 php can be in safe mode, when safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir.

2)Note to this function in php.net
    Note:

```
If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.
```

3) So you can try this [How to make php script run another php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110080/how-to-make-php-script-run-another-php-script) you can try this

```
 <?php
 $somearg = escapeshellarg('blah');
 exec("php file2.php $somearg > /dev/null &");
```

4) You can create a scheduled task [How to run a PHP file in a scheduled task (Windows Task Scheduler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: It is version php5.3.13 , also need a dynamic path to exe.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the earlier answers, let me add that if you want to execute a PHP file from within PHP, you may want to consider [the PHP function `include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) instead:

```
include $path."tester.php"
```

I guess that would be (much?) more efficient than to spawn a new shell which executes a new instance of PHP which executes the file. But of course the choice of the "better option" may depend on the context.