# calling a php script using exec() in wamp

Tags: php, exec

Using exec(), I am trying to run a php script that does a calculation but it doesn't seem to be running. I have confirmed permissions are set (tested with exex('whoami')).

CODE

```
echo exec('C:\wamp\www\module_calc>php calc.php "add" "1" "5"');
```

UPDATE:
Escaping the \ has not worked either

UPDATE: This worked

```
exec('cd "C:\wamp\www\\module_calc" && php calc.php "add" "1" "5"');
```

Answer (score 0):

See how you run a php-script via exec: [PHP exec to run a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961654/php-exec-run-a-file)

Better practice is to include and then call function:

```
include "C:\wamp\www\module_calc\calc.php";
add(1, 5);
```